# Power BI: sort by A-Z and then spaces

Tags: powerbi

I have a table visualisation I am building with a column of names. Now if the column has a name then it should be sorted A-Z, and if it is blank, then should be at the bottom of the table. Anytime I sort currently, the spaces are at the top of the table, followed by A-Z sorting. Any idea on how to solve this in Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a helper column for the sort order, because Power BI sorts blank before text.

You could use Power Query to extract a unique list of name values from the transaction table. Add a blank cell to that table, then create an Index column to assign a sort order to that column.  Add that helper table to the data model and create a relationship to the transaction table.

In the data model, set the index column of the helper table as the "Sort by" column for the names.

You can now use the name values from the helper table in visuals. When you sort by the helper table names, the sort order from the Index column will be applied.